# Исключать такие исторические личности or таких исторических личностей?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

> Размышлять подобным образом значит исключать из их числа **таких
>   исторических личностей** как Бендамор и Контратий.

What case should I use here? Accusative or Genitive?

Comment: Different cases should be used depending of whether you are want to exclude persons, or to exclude persons from the list of persons. Исключать из чего? - из числа личностей: "Исключать из числа таких личностЕЙ". Исключать что? - личности: "Исключать такие личностИ".

Comment: @Artemix "Исключать что? - личности: "Исключать такие личностИ"" - The thing is, the question "Исключать кого?" would also be possible and absolutely correct in this case. If so, then "Исключать такИХ личностЕЙ" would also be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What case should I use here? The accusative or the genitive?

You should without doubt use the accusative here, but I think you intended to ask whether *личность* is animate or not in this context (in other words, whether to use *кого?* or *что?* in the accusative).

I believe this passage from Rosenthal (153.5) would apply to *личность* as well, so your example is correct.:

> Слово *лицо* в значении «человек» употребляется во множественном числе как существительное одушевленное, например: *наградить отдельных лиц*.

**Update:**

From Yeskova's *Краткий словарь трудностей русского языка*:

> **ли́чность, -и, *мн.* -и, -ей,** *одуш. и неодуш.* ▭ *Человек, индивид (употр. с определением)* | Привлекал каких-то подозрительных ли́чностей (*и* какие-то подозрительные ли́чности)

Comment: care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Лицо and личность differ here. Наградить отдельных личностей is ungrammatical or sarcasmic, imitates uneducated speech.

Comment: @Anixx: there are lots of examples in the corpus which tell otherwise: *Я бы подобных личностей к аспирантуре не подпускала*, *Они подстерегают в основном самостоятельных личностей, решивших совершенствовать себя без помощи инструктора* and other.

Comment: first example seemingly sarcasmic (I think, the word "личностей" even can be put in quotes here), second example looks unnatural(or like a 19th century speech) to me.

Comment: @Anixx: do *я бы подобные личности к аспирантуре не подпускала* or *они подстерегают самостоятельные личности* seem natural to you?

Comment: yes, exactly. I think using "личностей" in the first sentence is quite rude and underlines the uneducatedness of those of whom the author speaks, thus it properly should be in quotes so to imitate potential speech of those people.

Comment: @Anixx: and what about the second sentence? Do you really think *самостоятельная личность* is inanimate?

Comment: Yes. If it were лиц, it would be natural to use it as animate.

Comment: I think you've nailed the very core of the question here, that is, if the word "личность" is animate, then it is absolutely correct to say "исключать таких исторических личностей". Can you, please, give me a link to that passage by Rosenthal?

Comment: @brilliant: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm

Comment: @brilliant Rosenthal talks about лицо, not about личность.

Comment: @brilliant The word личность is analogious to the word "персона". This word is also inanimate: он упрекал важные персоны в бездействии or он упрекал важных персон в бездействии - which one is correct? Obviously, the first. Similarly, the word "фигура". Он упрекал важные фигуры в бездействии vs он упрекал важных фигур в бездействии.

Comment: The word *личность* is inanimate. It is analogious with the words персона and фигура (when referring to people). Compare: > Он назвал важные персоны в правительстве.
> > Он назвал важных персон в правительстве.
> > Он назвал важные фигуры в правительстве.
> > Он назвал важных фигур в правительстве.
> > Он назвал важные личности в правительстве.
> > Он назвал важных личностей в правительстве. Quassnoi, do you consider "Он назвал важных фигур в правительстве." natural?

Comment: @Anixx: http://goo.gl/foSAAc. Note that both entries treat *персона* as animate. If you allow homonymy in the search you'll see much more entries with animate *персона* (you'll have to browse manually for them)

Comment: @Anixx: Also from Sasha Chorny: *Жестикулируя, бурля и споря // Киты редакции не видят двух персон // Поэт принёс "Ночную песню моря" // А беллетрист "Последний детский сон"*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10680/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-anixx)

Comment: WOW!!! Your update in the answer says it all. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Indeed `исключать` is a transitive verb that requires the accusative.

`личность` in the accusative plural is `личности` (see [morpher.ru](http://morpher.ru/?s=%eb%e8%f7%ed%ee%f1%f2%fc))

My variant:

> Размышлять подобным образом - значит исключать из их числа такие исторические личности, как Бендамор и Контратий.

Using the genitive with `личность` instead of the accusative (only in the plural) sounds very informal and not like an obvious grammatical error. It's also most often used jokingly.
I was able to google another usage of the genitive with this word where the accusative is supposed to be used:
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User_talk:Dart_evader

> Сорри, Дарт. Вы, конечно, правы - не надо увековечивать тут подобных личностей :-)

So by using the genitive here, we express a sort of sarcasm. It's no longer someone famous, but someone who's pretending to be famous. Hope this helps.

**Update** (some more examples):

http://www.uralskweek.kz/2013/09/02/shkolnik-iz-uralska-sozdal-socialnuyu-set/

```
собираемся приглашать знаменитых и интересных личностей
```

No sarcasm here, why not accusative? It's informal speach and the word is used in a different meaning (person, not personality).

I can't find a real example of accusative plural on the Internet. Need a different kind of search engine. But here is a more or less realistic example of my own:

```
В юности он старательно изучал личности Берии и Сталина, стараясь в чём-то даже походить на них.
```

Comment: Are you sure that [Nevermind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Nevermind) intentionally used genitive to express sarcasm? Looks like an error or typo for me.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. His usage was intuitive though. :) My conclusions about sarcasm are based on my own experience as a native speaker and some linguistic background. I found this meaning in the explanatory dictionary: http://www.efremova.info/word/lichnosti.html So we may use it in plural to hint at someone, to offend, hurt one's pride. And hence sarcasm.

Comment: I think Efremova's second case of личности is used in expression переходить на личности - "прямая критика личности или оскорбление оппонента" and not because genitive expresses sarcasm.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what the author wanted to say. As for your variant, it's ungrammatical. But there are two possible corrections with different meanings:

> Размышлять подобным образом значит исключать из их числа такие
> исторические личности как Бендамор и Контратий.
>
> Размышлять подобным образом значит исключать их из числа таких
> исторических личностей как Бендамор и Контратий.

So if you swap "их" and "из", the sentence becomes fully grammatical, but the meaning is different.

Comment: "As of your variant, it is ungrammatical" - As the recent update in Quassnoi's answer has shown, it is absolutely correct and grammatical.